# Twoside formatting layout in class

Tags: overleaf, double-sided

My college has a new latex template that is easy to use and beautiful. The other departments in the college have decided that no printed document is necessary, and so the template does not have a `twoside` or `openright` layout argument. It is not based on any memoir, book, or report class that would provide it.

My department, however, has decided that I still need a printed document, and is requiring empty pages with chapters opening on the right. What might I do to enable these features? My searching has not led to anything fruitful, instead just suggestions to use `twoside`, etc.

The full template is available on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/byu-engineering-thesis-slash-dissertation-template/dmvrdrhncrpy).

Comment: "It is not based on any memoir, book, or report class that would provide it."  it is memoir with some local additions

Comment: Ahh, just noticed that. Feeling silly, but I'll leave it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class is an extension of `memoir` it has

```
\LoadClass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}  % based off of memoir class
```

if you delete `oneside`

```
\LoadClass[letterpaper,11pt,openright]{memoir}  % based off of memoir class
```

the you can use `oneside` or `twoside` on `\documentclass`